# How do I put an adjustable pane in a multifragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 2 fragments displayed side by side. In between the two fragments, I have a view that acts as a barrier between the two fragments. What I want to be able to do is hold down on the view and drag it side to side where it would adjust the width of each fragment accordingly.

[image]

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you won't appreciate the answer, but that's something you shouldn't do. This pattern doesn't belong to mobile platforms.

Comment: I'd rather know now that it is a bad idea than later. I'm going to look at alternative frameworks. Probably something like the Side menu on the Google Maps app that allows the user to drag a menu out from the side. I am still curious if someone does know the answer in case a future customer imposed requirement ever force me to defy convention.